# How to flip Shape horizontally in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a `Shape` that need to be flipped along the x-axis. I'm looking for a way to solve this with `CGAffineTransform`, but I've only found a way to rotate the Shape, but not flipping along an axis. I need something like `.rotation3DEffect(.degrees(180), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))`for Shapes

Comment: Did you read my question? I'm looking for a solution for `Shape`, not for `View`

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `rotation3DEffect` on a shape.  Here's a simple example:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var degrees : Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyShape()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(degrees), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
            Button("Rotate") {
                withAnimation {
                    degrees = degrees == 0 ? 180 : 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyShape : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: .zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        }
    }
}
```

Just to avoid confusion, I would say that your question title and your example of `rotation3DEffect` code and your title (flip shape "horizontally") conflict a little in my mind -- rotating 180 degrees with `axis(x:1, y:0, z:0)` performs what I would consider a vertical flip. For horizontal, you can change it to `axis(x:0, y:1, z:0)`

Answer (score 5):

Here is way to get back a `Shape` (**some** `Shape`, I would say):

```
extension Shape {  
    func flipped() -> ScaledShape<Self> {
        scale(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center)
    }
}
```

If some more complex path manipulation is needed:

```
struct FlippedShape<Content>: Shape where Content : Shape {
    let content: Content
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let flip = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
        let position = flip.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: rect.width, y: 0))
        // some other path manipulation requiring `rect`
        return content.path(in: rect).applying(position)
    }
}

extension Shape {
    func flipped() -> FlippedShape<Self> {
        FlippedShape(content: self)
    }
}
```